# My loop isn't drawing anything to the screen

Tags: java, loops, processing

I'm having difficulty with a simple while loop.

```
size(500,500);
background(255);
rectMode(CENTER);
noCursor();

int x1 = mouseX;
int y1 = mouseY;
int count = 0;
fill(0);
rect(250,250,50,50); //this is drawn
while (count == 0); {
  fill(0);
  rect(250,250,50,50); //this is not
}
```

Its written in Processing.
Anything I have in the while loop isn't drawn, while anything after it isn't either. Anything before it, not in a loop, is drawn. What am I missing here?

Comment: while loop is infinite.

Comment: I believe that `while` is falling into a endless loop; `count` is always zero in that piece of code you shared. Therefore, you are endlessly filling everything black, and the painting. Due to the speed of the program I believe you are not able to percieve it is being drawn and erased every time.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your while loop, you have a `;` which is ending the while loop and will not execute it, replace your while-loop with:

```
while (count == 0) {
  fill(0);
  rect(250,250,50,50); //this is not
}
```

In Processing you shouldn't create infinite loops like you're doing, there is a `draw()` function which you can write which will do a similar thing:

```
void draw() {
  fill(0);
  rect(250,250,50,50); //this is not
}
```

This needs to be accompanies with a `setup()` function, the setup function only runs once in the beginning of the program:

```
int x1,y1;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  background(255);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  x1 = mouseX;
  y1 = mouseY;
  fill(128);
  rect(250,250,50,50); //this is drawn
}
void draw(){
    fill(0);
    rect(250,250,50,50); //this is not
}
```

Maybe you're new to processing but you should consider using this layout as it is the core of the framework.

Comment: We have been using the draw() function, but this time it was required to draw an object to the screen by using our own loops. Why is it that I shouldn't use an infinite loop? Doesn't it accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is half right. Your `while` loop ends with a `;` semicolon, so it's just going to continually loop without doing anything.

> We have been using the draw() function, but this time it was required to draw an object to the screen by using our own loops. Why is it that I shouldn't use an infinite loop? Doesn't it accomplish the same thing?

No. Even if you fix the semicolon problem, you'll still never see anything on the screen. That's because stuff is only shown on the screen when the code completes! If you have a `draw()` function, it's only shown at the end of the `draw()` function. If you don't, then it's only shown at the end of the program. Having an infinite loop prevents anything from being shown on the screen.

However, you don't have to have a `setup()` and `draw()` function. You just can't have an infinite loop. (The same thing is true if you do have a `draw()` function, btw.)

Note that the code in your `while` loop doesn't actually change, so you can just get rid of the `while` part. But also note that running your code without a `draw()` function means that `mouseX` and `mouseY` will always be `0`.